# Creating a SASS function to calculate the width based on vuejs prop

Tags: vue.js, sass, vue-props

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to create a function in sass which takes 2 prop values, calculates the percentage and returns the percentage as a width value. I am using bootstraps progress bar.

The class needs to be dynamic so if the result is 32 then the bar needs to be 32%.

Here is the container that controls the width of the progress bar

```
<div
  class="progress-bar bg-success"
  :class="'width-' + value"
  role="progressbar"
  :aria-valuenow="value"
  aria-valuemin="0"
  aria-valuemax="100"
></div>


<script>
export default {
  name: "Bar",
  props: {
    bar: String,
    value: Number,
    totalValue: Number
  }

};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@function bar-width() {
  @return width(value/totalValue * 100);
}
</style>
```

This is what I've got so far, I feel like I'm on the right track, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to dissapoint you but you are on the completely wrong track. SASS functions are executed at build time only (SASS compiles into pure CSS) so you cannot use it at runtime (when your Vue app is running inside user's browser)

Answer (score 0):

As @MichalLevý correctly pointed out in the comments, it is not possible to do what you want. SCSS is generated on compile time and Vue is executed on runtime. So all combinations must already be defined at compile time.

You basically have two options to solve your problem anyway: Either you generate all possible classes with SCSS (so 100 classes in case you only have integer percentage values), which seems like an unnecessary amount of code to is deliver to each client. Or you just use a dynamic style attribute and bind the percentage value into that attribute with regular Vue.

I would prefer the second approach, because it is cleaner. There is however the caveat that you cannot use CSP in that case without adding `unsafe-inline` to the style part. There is however still the possibility to then set the style property with JavaScript (without using the style attribute) when the value changes (Vue watcher).

Here is the second solution in its simplest form:

```
<div :style="{ width: `${percent}%` }" />
```